# Analysing mesh hole sizes

Tags: chi-squared-test

I have generated some data in an image analysis programme for some woven wire mesh. I have sampled 5 random holes (could easily sample more/less if that helps) and the software has given me a statistic for each sampled hole that tells me how square each hole is, i.e. the aspect ratio (length of longest side divided by shorter side). Perfect mesh would have aspect ratios of 1 as all holes would be exactly square; however the holes are never perfect so aspect ratios are never quite 1 (always greater, never less) as holes are usually v. slightly rectangular.

I would like to analyse the data to see if the mesh is significantly different from 'perfect mesh'. Example data for 5 sampled holes is 1.066, 1.054, 1.048, 1.034, 1.034. How can I check to see if this sample is statistically significant or not?

I thought about using chi-square statistic, with 1 as expected value for all samples; however, realised that expected values need to be at least 5 and total of expected values must be a minimum of 50, which counts my data out. Is there an alternative out there I could use that doesn't mind 'small values'?

Then I wondered could I simply calculate the mean (1.047) and standard deviation (0.014) and if the mean +/- 2xS.D. (1.020-1.075) contains the value 1 (perfect mesh) assume with 95% confidence the mesh my samples were taken from is not significantly different to perfect mesh? In this case 1 does not lie within 2 standard deviations of the mean and therefore I assume the mesh does not have square holes. However, as data will always be slightly greater than 1, 1 will never lie within 95% of 'normally distributed' data; so guessing this is wrong approach.

Has anyone got any advice please?

Answer (score 0):

"however the holes are never perfect so aspect ratios are never quite 1 (always greater, never less)" If you do know that already, there is no point in testing, whether the mean of the aspect ratios is zero. There is no point in testing what is known before.
Your test with 2*sd could be refined and then become a t-test. Of course, you could t-test, whether the mean of your values is larger then 1, but then again, if you know that beforehand, it really makes no sense.

Comment: Thanks for help. When calculating aspect ratios I'm guessing I'd be better off dividing side A by side B (predetermined), irrespective of which is the longer. That way, for example, 2 holes measuring 100mm x 95mm and 95mm x 100mm, would give aspect ratio values of 1.053 and 0.95, respectively (instead of 1.053 twice). This way I would avoid always producing data with values greater than 1 and could then test to see if on average mesh is square or not. Does that make sense?

Comment: That does not seem to be a good idea unless we talk about the geometric mean. 2/1 and 1/2's arithmetic mean is not 1. How about the difference of the 'square's' sides' lengths?  It will of course depend on tha question you are trying to answer with your examination.